# Show all jpg from a directory as a slideshow time lapse with timeline

Tags: php, html

Well, the title says it all.
I have a working php code to show all images simply (code below), but what I would like to do is have them play like a slideshow, but quite a fast one, so it looks like a time-lapse.
Ideally the viewer can manipulate a cursor on a horizontal timeline at the bottom of the page.
I thought PHP could be used, but maybe html5 etc?
Thank you all for help.

```
<?php
    $files = glob("images/*.*");
    for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
    {
        $image = $files[$i];
        $supported_file = array(
        'gif',
        'jpg',
        'jpeg',
        'png'
        );
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        if (in_array($ext, $supported_file)) {
            //print $image ."<br />";
            echo '<img src="'.$image .'" alt="Random image" />'."<br /><br />";
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You need a client side solution for this, so javascript.

Comment: Ok so wrong tags and wrong question I suppose.

Comment: The question does make sense, but it is off-topic here. You ask for a recommendation.

Comment: Ok, I only know how to do slow slide shows though.  On a serious note you may want to look at some pre-build JavaScript libraries that do this. PHP (server side languages) don't do animation of this type, you have to use a Clientside Language, such as JavaScript.  However there is a billion prebuilt plugins out there for this.